# How can Users manage and keep their in-app purchases with my app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

please I need some help. I developed a mobile app for a client. Within the app, users can purchase video courses that they can watch. But my challenge now is that when a user buys a course, if he refreshes the app and comes back to the course, he's taken back to the payment page of that same course he already paid for, instead of being taken to the course. I have been trying to figure out a way to solve this, I don't know if anyone can help me. The app is built on HTML5. I don't know if anyone has a Learning Management System Code or something like that, that's based on HTML that can resolve this. Or better still, I appreciate if you can help me figure this out in anyway. Thanks

Comment: You can create a table that holds all transactions, with the `id` of the users and the `id` of the purchased video as columns

Comment: You need to keep a trace of that payement.

Comment: Please note, the app was built using an app builder that's based on HTML, with each page having editable backend code. And I don't really know much about codes

Answer (score 0):

A solid way to achieve this is to store the values in a database with a unique ID, and perform an AJAX call when you load the app to see who has payed for which parts of the app. You can create a simple API to write all approved transactions to, and perform a GET request on that API to check if the current user has any purchased items.

If you use something like cookies, or even local storage, the data can be wiped relatively easily, and it will be hard or even impossible to track who has and hasn't payed for what.